# Unable to cascade CSS to input control but able to for other HTML in DOM in Razor

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor, fonts

I have a div styled *input-data*. In it, there's a span and an input control. In my CSS, I'm setting *font-size*. It does cascade to the span control but not the input. I need to set it explicitly there. So, when I manupulate the size 40 to 30, I see a change in the span but not in the input.

```
div.input-data {
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 40px;
}

div.input-data span {
  /*font-size: 20px;*/
}

div.input-data input {
  /*font-size: 20px;*/
}
```

Of course, I can get what I want by setting the size eplicitly removing the comment in the last style but it seems to me like giving up to the computers. And anybody who's seen Terminator knows what happens if computers win.

Are there different cascading rules to inputs? Can it have to do with the generating procedure (I'm using *Html.TextBoxFor*, although the produced HTML seems the same)?

```
<div class="input-data">
  <span>Nickname</span>
  @Html.TextBoxFor(vehicle => vehicle.Name)
  @*@Html.TextBoxFor(vehicle => vehicle.Name, new { @class = "input-data" })*@
</div>
```

I've tried sending in the style into the generator too, as seen in the commented out part. Same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do `div.input-data * { font-size:xx; }`.

Just a little less code, but you're not giving up totally...

Comment: Well, wouldn't you know! That worked... I still want to know why it doesn't without it... It does work for span but not for input...

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not too farmiliar with Razor, that's just plain css solution.

Answer (score 1):

Different browsers set different default CSS rules and the problem may have root in those rules that is called `user agent stylesheet` and can be fixed with attaching [Normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) in your page or just set the CSS below

```
button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  color: inherit; /* 1 */
  font: inherit; /* 2 */
  margin: 0; /* 3 */
}
```

Comment: I'll try that, of course. However, I sense that it's not going to do the trick because, as it seems, the style isn't cascaded down to the input control. Even if the browser (Cr in this case) would be doing something behind the curtains, I'd expect the priority to be on the code side and only invoking the default CSS settings when nothing else is being told. In this case it **is** told. However, I know for sure tomorrow, when I'm more rested in my brains, so I can test reliably..

Comment: Every browser has its own default ‘user agent’ stylesheet, that it uses to make unstyled websites appear more legible. Obviously this creates a certain amount of headaches for CSS authors, who can’t work out how to make their websites look the same in every browser.